# DT bindings for ADT7516 sensor

Tags: linux, drivers, embedded, device-tree, iio

I have a BeagleBone green and ADT7516's evaluation board connected with SDA and SCL pins.

When I do i2cdetect -y -r 2, I can see the i2c address as 0x4b and I am able to probe the adt7316 driver present in IIO subsystem.

adt7316 driver uses platform data to get the hardware description. But my goal is to remove platform data and use DT bindings.

I understand some basic things about the DT bindings like..

1. Compatible
2. reg

But when I have a close look at the driver, I can see that there are certain
things which are taken from the platform data and are used in the whole driver.

So my question is that how do I replace those things in the driver if I remove platform data and use DT bindings.

I am putting probe function's code here.

```
int adt7316_probe(struct device *dev, struct adt7316_bus *bus,
    const char *name)
{
struct adt7316_chip_info *chip;
struct iio_dev *indio_dev;
unsigned short *adt7316_platform_data = dev->platform_data;
int ret = 0;

indio_dev = devm_iio_device_alloc(dev, sizeof(*chip));
if (!indio_dev)
    return -ENOMEM;
chip = iio_priv(indio_dev);
/* this is only used for device removal purposes */
dev_set_drvdata(dev, indio_dev);

chip->bus = *bus;

if (name[4] == '3')
    chip->id = ID_ADT7316 + (name[6] - '6');
else if (name[4] == '5')
    chip->id = ID_ADT7516 + (name[6] - '6');
else
    return -ENODEV;

chip->ldac_pin = adt7316_platform_data[1];
if (chip->ldac_pin) {
    chip->config3 |= ADT7316_DA_EN_VIA_DAC_LDCA;
    if ((chip->id & ID_FAMILY_MASK) == ID_ADT75XX)
        chip->config1 |= ADT7516_SEL_AIN3;
}
chip->int_mask = ADT7316_TEMP_INT_MASK | ADT7316_VDD_INT_MASK;
if ((chip->id & ID_FAMILY_MASK) == ID_ADT75XX)
    chip->int_mask |= ADT7516_AIN_INT_MASK;

indio_dev->dev.parent = dev;
if ((chip->id & ID_FAMILY_MASK) == ID_ADT75XX)
    indio_dev->info = &adt7516_info;
else
    indio_dev->info = &adt7316_info;
indio_dev->name = name;
indio_dev->modes = INDIO_DIRECT_MODE;

if (chip->bus.irq > 0) {
    if (adt7316_platform_data[0])
        chip->bus.irq_flags = adt7316_platform_data[0];

    ret = devm_request_threaded_irq(dev, chip->bus.irq,
                    NULL,
                    adt7316_event_handler,
                    chip->bus.irq_flags |
                    IRQF_ONESHOT,
                    indio_dev->name,
                    indio_dev);
    if (ret)
        return ret;

    if (chip->bus.irq_flags & IRQF_TRIGGER_HIGH)
        chip->config1 |= ADT7316_INT_POLARITY;
}

ret = chip->bus.write(chip->bus.client, ADT7316_CONFIG1, chip->config1);
if (ret)
    return -EIO;

ret = chip->bus.write(chip->bus.client, ADT7316_CONFIG3, chip->config3);
if (ret)
    return -EIO;

ret = devm_iio_device_register(dev, indio_dev);
if (ret)
    return ret;

dev_info(dev, "%s temperature sensor, ADC and DAC registered.\n",
        indio_dev->name);

return 0;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(adt7316_probe);
```

So in the code we can see that **chip->ldac_pin** and **chip->bus.irq_flags** uses
platform data.
If I use DT bindings then platform data will have NULL value in it.

So how do I design my DT bindings here and how can I fetch that data in the driver?

I have seen many examples of DT bindings but I need specific help with adt7516 sensor.

**Datasheet of adt7516 sensor**

http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADT7516_7517_7519.pdf